# ElasticSearch Multiword synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine, synonym

I have analyzer with synonyms

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym", 
      "synonyms": [
        "st,str,street",             
        "district of columbia,dc"
      ]
    }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonyms" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I run analysis on "street", it gives me that "st" and "str" are synonyms.

But if I run on "DC", it gives me that "district", "of" and "columbia" are synonyms.

How to make "DC" and "District of Columbia" synonyms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the synonyms as below :

```
"filter": {
    "synonyms": {
      "type": "synonym", 
      "synonyms": [
         "st,str,street",             
          "district of columbia,dc=>dc"
       ]
    }
}
```

Please check the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html) for more details

Comment: it half helped. If i search "New Jersey" - it finds "NJ", but if I search "NJ" it doesn't finds "New Jersea"

Comment: Did you try reindexing the docs after updating the settings ?

Comment: I will try reindexing and than check this. I didn't have time to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your analyzer.tokenizer to "keyword",

```
"analyzer": {
    "synonyms": {
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "synonyms" 
      ]
    }
  }
```

This treats "district of columbia" as a single entity and maps to "DC"